# Jenkins - Bitbucket PR builder not building correct branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, pull-request

I am setting up my Jenkinsfile to allow for tests to build on every bitbucket PR made for any branch (only on PR). However, the plugin seems to be building against every branch when a PR is made. Is this a bug with the plugin? I am using Bitbucket Pull Request Builder plugin 1.4.30

My trigger is as follows

```
 triggers{

-    bitbucketpr(projectPath:'bitbucket.org/testrepo/django-db.git',

-      cron:'* * * * *',

-      credentialsId:'jenkins_pr_test',

-      repositoryOwner:'testrepo',

-      repositoryName:'django-db',

-      branchesFilter:"*/dev",

-      branchesFilterBySCMIncludes:false,

-      ciKey:'jenkins',

-      ciName:'jenkins',

-      ciSkipPhrases:'',

-      checkDestinationCommit:false,

-      approveIfSuccess:false,

-      cancelOutdatedJobs:true,

-      commentTrigger:'')

-    pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')

-  }
```

I have even tried the following to build against only a specific branch, but the plugin still builds all branches.

````
-      branchesFilter:"*/${BRANCH_NAME}"```
````

Any ideas?

My stage is as follows

```
     stage('Build and Test Docker image') {

      when { branch "${BRANCH_NAME}" }

       steps {

         script {

            docker.withRegistry("${env.ECR_URL}", "ecr:us-east-1:ecrAccess") {

               customImage = docker.build("${env.IMAGE_NAME}")

               withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'CODACY_TARGETDB_API', variable: 'CODACY_PROJECT_TOKEN')]) {

                 sh "curl -L \"https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-\$(uname -s)-\$(uname -m)\" -o docker-compose"

                 sh "chmod +x docker-compose"

                 sh "./docker-compose -f docker-compose-ci.yml up --exit-code-from web"

               }

               customImage.push()

           }

         }

       }
```

Comment: Did you consider using a multibranch Pipeline with the Bitbucket branch source plugin? Just looking at the configuration it should not only be easier to use but also do what you need and nicely display branches and PRs separately. You can configure how to handle branches for which a PR exists.

Comment: Hmm I actually am using that as well. I wonder if they are conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

In the Triggers block edit the projectPath with

```
*/${sourceBranch}
```

It should look like this:

```
bitbucketpr(projectPath:'*/${sourceBranch}',
```